# Migrate Java 8 CompletionStage to Vertx Future

Tags: java, vert.x

I am trying to convert my Quarkus vertx example codes to Vertx 4.0, and find some problems.

For example, [the original method in Quarkus](https://github.com/hantsy/quarkus-sample/blob/master/vertx-routes/src/main/java/com/example/PostsHandler.java) using Java 8 CompletionStage.

```java
        this.posts.findAll()
                .thenAccept(
                        data -> rc.response()
                                .end(toJson(data))
                );
```

And convert to [Vertx Future codes](https://github.com/hantsy/vertx-sandbox).

```java
        this.posts.findAll()
            .onSuccess(
                data -> rc.response().end(Json.encode(data))
            );
```

The Java 8 CompletionStages `thenApply`, `thenCompose` can be converted to `map`, `flatmap/compose` in the Vertx codes.

There is NO equivalent method to `thenAccept`.

Answer (score 1):

Vert.x `Future` is not a JDK `CompletionStage`.

This is why it doesn't have a `thenAccept` method.

But, as you found out, `onSuccess` plays a similar role.